# List<Messaging.Singleemailmessage> causes error in Trigger

Tags: trigger

[image]

Trigger:

```
 if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
    for (Opportunity fOpp : trigger.new) {
        if (fOpp.StageName == 'Closed Lost - Client Declined') {
            stgclosedlost.add(fOpp);
            stageName = trigger.oldmap.get(fOpp.Id).StageName;
            stagemap.put(fopp.id, stageName);
            appProcessName = trigger.oldmap.get(fOpp.Id).Process_Approval__c;
            Processmap.put(fOpp.id, appProcessName);
        }
    }
}

if (stgclosedlost.size() > 0) {
    OpportunityApproval.sendEmailToFinaceRegionalHead1(stgclosedlost, stagemap, Processmap);
}
```

---

```
public class OpportunityApproval {
    public static void sendEmailToFinaceRegionalHead1(List<Opportunity>
            opList, map<id, string> stageName, map<id, String>appProcessName) {
        //Custom settings
        Finance_and_RegionalHead__c financeUserIds = Finance_and_RegionalHead__c.getInstance('Finance');
        system.debug('>>>>>>finacne>>>>' + financeUserIds.User_Ids__c);
        string Finaceuserid = financeUserIds.User_Ids__c;
        User finaceUserEmail = [select id, email from user where id = :Finaceuserid];
        system.debug('######' + finaceUserEmail.email);
        Finance_and_RegionalHead__c ReginonalHeadUserIds = Finance_and_RegionalHead__c.getInstance('Regional Head');
        string regionalid = ReginonalHeadUserIds.User_Ids__c;
        User RegionalHeadEmail = [select id, email from user where id = :regionalid];
        system.debug('####' + RegionalHeadEmail.email);
        //end


        //currentProcessApproval=appProcessName;
        system.debug('currentProcessApproval@@@@@@@' + currentProcessApproval);
        emailTemplate = [select Id, Name, HtmlValue, Body, Subject from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName = 'Notification_to_Opportunity_Approver'];

        //build the email message
        List<Messaging.Singleemailmessage> email = new List<Messaging.Singleemailmessage>();
        list<User> users = new list<User>();
        set<Id> oppOwnerIds = new set<id>();
        map<id, user> usermap = new map<id, user>();
        map<id, opportunity> opportunitymap = new map<id, opportunity>();

        list<string> toAddresses1 = new list<string>();

        for (Opportunity op : opList) {
            oppOwnerIds.add(op.ownerId);
        }

        List<user> userList = [SELECT Id, ManagerId, manager.name, manager.email FROM User WHERE Id in:oppOwnerIds];
        for (User u : userList) {
            usermap.put(u.id, u);
        }


        List<Opportunity> opprty = [select Id, Owner.Name, Owner.Email from Opportunity where Id in:opList];
        for (Opportunity op : opprty) {
            opportunitymap.put(op.id, op);
        }

        for (Opportunity nOpp : opList) { //Opportunity for Loop

            string baseURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
            string OPPORTUNITY_URL = (baseURL + '/' + nOpp.Id);
            string FinanceEmailId = finaceUserEmail.email;
            string DivisionalEmailId = RegionalHeadEmail.email;


            if (FinanceEmailId != null) {
                toAddresses1.add(FinanceEmailId);
            }

            if (DivisionalEmailId != null) {
                toAddresses1.add(DivisionalEmailId);
            }
            //toAddresses1.add('annappaph2@gmail.com');
            String subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
            subject = subject.replace(' {!Opportunity.Name} ', nOpp.Name);
            subject = subject.replace('{!Opportunity.StageName}', nOpp.StageName);
            String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace(' {!Opportunity.Name} ', nOpp.Name);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.StageName}', nOpp.StageName);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!currentProcessApproval}', stageName.get(nOpp.id));
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}', opportunitymap.get(nOpp.id).Owner.Name);
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!ownermail}', opportunitymap.get(nOpp.id).Owner.Name);

            if (userList.size() > 0) {
                if (usermap.get(nOpp.ownerid).manager.name != null && usermap.get(nOpp.ownerid).manager.email != null && usermap.get(nOpp.ownerid).manager.name != '' && usermap.get(nOpp.ownerid).manager.email != '') {
                    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Managername}', usermap.get(nOpp.ownerid).manager.name);
                    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Email_of_Owner_s_Manager__c}', usermap.get(nOpp.ownerid).manager.email);
                } else {
                    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Managername}', 'Opportunity Manager not present');
                    htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Email_of_Owner_s_Manager__c}', 'Opportunity Manager Email not present');

                }
            } else {
                htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Managername}', 'Opportunity Manager not present');
                htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Email_of_Owner_s_Manager__c}', 'Opportunity Manager Email not present');
            }
            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!Opportunity.Link}', OPPORTUNITY_URL);

            String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;
            plainBody = plainBody.replace(' {!Opportunity.Name} ', nOpp.Name);
            plainBody = plainBody.replace('{!Opportunity.StageName}', nOpp.StageName);


            email.setSenderDisplayName('#######');
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
            email.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);

        }

        //for loop end


        //sending Emails
        if (toAddresses1.size() > 0) {
            //email.setToAddresses(toAddresses1);
            //Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage[] {email});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SingleEmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) methods are applicable to its instance, not to a List.

Either change the list declaration:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> email = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
```

to object instance:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
```

Or fill in the new instance of singleEmailObject's and add to the list for sending the email.

Comment: Ya I got that...Thats right. If I declare List means why its throwing error.That what I want to understand can you please explain me bit.its more helful

Comment: A `List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>` simply doesn't has those methods which you're trying to access; hence you get the error.